# Browsergame for PC and tablet - which plug-in to rely on?

Tags: java, silverlight, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am part of a student project working to create a free educational chemistry **browser** game, but we can't decide on which plug-in to use (Flash, Java, Unity...).

The game will consist of 2d graphics and short movie-scenes and it will mainly be a drag-and-drop game.

We want it (the plug-in) to be supported for the next several years and compatible with most (if not all) PCs and tablets - so Flash is already out of the question.

We're horrible programmers, but we have some funding, so we will outsource the actual programming, which means that it is also relevant whether we can find people able to work with the plug-in.

**So which plug-in would you recommend to our needs?** Pros and cons are very welcome.

Also please do tell if I've left out some relevant points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option is to avoid plugins entirely.

Apple iPad and iPhones don't support flash as you know, but they don't support any other plugins either.

Flash is supported on most (but not all) Android tablets and phones *up to and including Android 4.0*. But Adobe (makers of the flash plugin) have **discontinued** it and said that it will **not** be supplied for Android versions *above 4.0*.

Even on Android 4.0, users who have installed and are using the Chrome browser instead of the default browser, will not be able to view flash because even though the Android 4.0 OS might have a flash plugin, the Chrome browser when installed on Android 4.0 has not been designed to use it.

Android apps are written in Java, but the Android web browser doesn't actually include a plugin for running Java applets. Plugins are basically being phased out across the board, regardless of the OS or browser.

The best strategy:

- To reach the widest number of users
- Regardless of the type of PC, tablet, or browser they use
- And which will not result in the game becoming unsupported by browsers in in the long term

is to design your app using web standards.

These days, HTML 5 Canvas, CSS, JavaScript, and other technologies, which have been standardized to be supported across all web browsers, allow complex animations/graphics inside the browser, support drag and drop, and support playing video, without using any plugins at all. You could look at outsourcing development to a team which knows these technologies.

Since you are also looking at video, be aware though that there is an ongoing debate surrounding the `<video>` tag in HTML 5 (the feature which allows videos to be played without plugins). Basically it has been agreed that all browsers will allow videos to be played without plugins, but the actual format of the video which the  tag should support, was left out of the standard (due to disagreements) and so has not been decided.

The candidate video formats being debated include [WebM/VP8](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/01/html-video-codec-support-in-chrome.html), [H.264/MPEG-4 AVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) and [Theora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theora).

The workaround to this issue, is that the HTML 5 `<video>` tag allows you to list *multiple sources* for a video (i.e. multiple files on your server, all for the same video but in different formats). So if you save your videos in the most common formats, the browser can then choose the best format that it supports.

The HTML 5 video format debate therefore would not impact the design of your game (much), it just might give you a headache in needing to save videos in multiple formats. If you do this then your game would have wide compatibility across all of the major browsers.